# Highlight or apply `overflow: visible` to search result DOM elements (Chrome built-in search)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, frontend

Is there a way to hook into the Chrome's built-in search-in-page feature (i.e. `CTRL/Command + F`) (ideally without replacing it entirely)?

I am dealing with a large table with a lot of cropped text in cells. When searching for text on this page, it scrolls to the right row, but does not show me which cell contains the search result, meaning I don't know which cell or even which row has the result.

Natually, I would like to somehow highlight or otherwise make visible that what is hidden, but it does not seem possible...? Any recommendations?